# Python module for date manipulation

Tags: python, r, date

Is there a python module specifically for date manipulation. Something equivalent to the [lubridate](https://github.com/hadley/lubridate/blob/master/DESCRIPTION) package in R.

Comment: try `datetime` module... `http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The python module [arrow](https://pypi.org/project/arrow/) seems to be an equivalent of the R lubridate package:

```
import arrow
In [9]: arrow.get('Julie was born in May 1990', 'MMM YYYY')
Out[9]: <Arrow [1990-05-01T00:00:00+00:00]>
```

Answer (score 8):

Python have a built-in module for handling [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html)..You can try that..!!

But if want something extended (like want to build a generic datetime parser), go for [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
datetimeObj = parse(strDate) 
# str date is a date string
```

Answer (score 4):

Actually, Python's standard `datetime` module is pretty basic.  If you want more extensive and flexible date handling, you can try [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) or [mxDateTime](http://www.egenix.com/products/python/mxBase/mxDateTime/).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pytz

Documentation
http://pytz.sourceforge.net/